# How to find a list of all groups that I am a member of in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

How do I find a list of all groups that I am a member of for an organization in GCP? I am able to go to the **IAM > Groups** page and see a list of member users for an individual selected group, but I have not been able to find a list of all of the groups that I am a part of.

I found the [View a user's group memberships](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/167104?hl=en) article that walks through the steps of seeing a user's group memberships, but this requires an admin account. I am not an admin and only want to see my own group memberships. How can I do this?

Comment: I know this is tagged as google cloud and not google workspace, but aren't you just looking for https://groups.google.com/my-groups ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! If you write this as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution. I updated the question tags as well.

Comment: Is there a way to get this list programmatically, via some documented API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For general google workspace groups, there is this page that shows an overview for the currently logged in account:

https://groups.google.com/my-groups

Comment: This displays my GCP groups as well. Thanks!